# Generating a boolean matrix in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm new for programming and having some trouble with coding this and please anyone kindly help.

I have a dictionary and a list such as:

```
dic = {1:[1,3], 2:[2,4], 3:[1,5]}
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How can I check if each element in the list exists in the dictionary and output a boolean matrix (by the dictionary key)? Thank you!

```
   1     2      3
1 TRUE   FALSE  TRUE
2 FALSE  TRUE   FALSE
3 TRUE   FALSE  FALSE
4 FALSE  TRUE   FALSE
5 FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
```

#Columns are each key in the dictionary. Rows are each element in the list.

Comment: could you post the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: Does the dic variable represent the coordinates you are trying to mark as True? I am not sure if I understand your intent correctly

Comment: Not optimized dict comprehension: `{k:[i in v for i in list] for k,v in dic.items()}`. Also note that you should not use `list` as a variable as it shadows the built-in `list` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dic = {1:[1,3], 2:[2,4], 3:[1,5]}
list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #notice the underscore "list_"

matrix = [[item in value for value in dic.values()] 
                         for item in list_]
```

Or, more verbose but easier to understand:

```
dic = {1:[1,3], 2:[2,4], 3:[1,5]}
list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

matrix = []
for item in list_:
    row = []
    for value in dic.values():
        row.append(item in value)
    matrix.append(row)
```

Edit:
what @SM Abu Taher Asif said, don't use 'list' as a variable name, it is a reserved keyword and using it that way might lead to bugs. If you have to, use 'ls' or 'list_' that's the common practice.

Comment: Thank you tornikeo for the kind explanation and two version of code. This solved my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as you need to build a matrix that is 2D array, you can create a list of lists:

```
dic = {1:[1,3], 2:[2,4], 3:[1,5]}
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

ansMatrix = []
for r in lst :
    temp = []
    for k in dic:
        if r in dic[k]:
            temp.append(True)
        else:
            temp.append(False)
    ansMatrix.append(temp)
print(ansMatrix)
```

output:

```
[[True, False, True], [False, True, False], [True, False, False], [False, True, False], [False, False, True]]
```

list is a keyword , so don't use that as names.
you can try list comprehension mentioned in the comment

```
ansMatrixUsingListComp = [ [r in dic[k] for k in dic ] for r in lst ]
```

Comment: Thank you SM Abu for your kind advice and the comment about the variable name. Thank you.